# How to change resetZoomButton text (Vaadin Charts)?

Tags: charts, vaadin, vaadin-charts

Does anybody know how to change reseZoomButton text ("Reset zoom" in original)?
It seems that the Highcharts object must be used for this. How to access to it inside Vaadin Charts?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following js must be executed before creating Chart object:

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/js/es-modules/parts/Globals.js';

window.change = function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        lang: {
                resetZoom: 'Сброс',
                resetZoomTitle: 'Установить масштаб 1:1',
    }
 });
```

}

Important thing is that Highchart import must be from the script as shown in the code.